# A way to store web app userdata offsite (local + common cloud storage)

Tags: web-applications, cloud, storage

I like to serve an application with personal (per user) data. The easy way would be to store it in my database. But I don't like to do that. I like the data to be stored in a cloud service that only the particular User can reach, and he gives the application permission to it. I had an idea to use Google Sheets for such a thing, but it feels a bit clunky.

So my question is - do anyone know of a good per user cloud data storage? And even better - one that also has a local webstorage ability. With the latter I mean the user should have the data locally until he asks to upload it. That part might of course be something for my app, but perhaps there is some storage where it's already built in.

Answer (score 1):

For offline storage, HTML5 can support this, although I have not used it. And for cloud storage you could use Amazon Simple DB or RDS with MySQL. Why does each user need a separate database?

Another option for a per user database is MongoHQ, https://mongohq.com/pricing.

Also there are a lot of options for nosql talked about in this question: [Is there any NoSQL database as simple as SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403174/is-there-any-nosql-database-as-simple-as-sqlite), it might be an option for the local storage.

Comment: I want them to be independent from us and also have the possibility to use another service provider on the same data. For now Google Sheets or Dropbox is my best options. For the local storage option I would need a backup to the cloud also.

Answer (score 0):

Storing local data offline can be done using local web storage. 5 Mb of data can be stored using webstorage. The basic tutorial is explained [here](http://www.techrecite.com/webstorage-html5-local-offline-browser-storage/)